# Right Shift not working properly

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I am right shifting an unsigned int by 32 but it doesn't affect the number at all, why is it happening?

```
int main()
{
  unsigned int rnd=2347483648;
  cout<<rnd;
  rnd=rnd>>32;
  cout<<endl<<rnd;
}
```

When the code runs, it displays rnd twice,showing no affect at all. I believe that after right shifting a 32 bit int, shouldn't it display zero?

Comment: Gotta love these "core language feature X not working" questions... couldn't you just pay a little more attention to the book/tutorial you are reading?

Comment: Well rnd=rnd>>32 shows the same result, i tried that too... but it should display 0 right?

Comment: Now see the question again, this is the question actually..

Comment: Oh, I see. It is marked as a duplicate. I have to admit that the title of this question is much better and search-friendlier. To be honest, quite likely the question is duplicate only once you know the answer and know where to look for duplicates.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are missing an assignment operator - the `>>` shift operator does not perform the operation "in-place":

```
rnd = rnd >> 32;
```

You could also use the compound shift operator, which applies the shift operation and then assigns the result back to the variable:

```
rnd >>= 32;
```

However, in both cases, this code results in *undefined behaviour*, see  [Shifting a 32 bit integer by 32 bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18799344/shifting-a-32-bit-integer-by-32-bits):

> If the value of the right operand is negative or is greater than **or equal** to the width of the promoted left operand, the behavior is undefined.

So you could get any result from that operation.

Comment: Note that there's also compound shift operators, `a <<= b` and `a >>= b`

Comment: @SBI good point - that would probably count as "in-place" :)

Comment: see the question now... this is what i mean.... shifting by 32 should result 0 but why it's not happening?

Comment: Read the answer carefully. The important point is: This is undefined behavior! That means: It should not result in 0. It can be anything, including NOP.

Comment: Under x86 that "undefined" behaviour means that shifting does not occur. The second argument is interpreted modulo the first argument width in bits. So, shift 33 bits means shift 1 bit. Shift 64 bits means again no shift.

Answer (score 4):

Shifting by the number of bits in the promoted operand type, or more, gives undefined behaviour. `unsigned int` is typically 32 bits, so that typically applies when shifting by 32 or more bits as you do here.

This is because different processors behave in different ways when a shift overflows, and the language designers didn't want to prevent implementations from using the processor's built-in shift instruction by specifying a particular behaviour.

Answer (score 3):

The bit-shift operator doesn't modify the original data. It simply returns a modified copy.

I think this is what you meant to do:

```
rnd = rnd >> 32;
```

Assuming your `unsigned int` is 32-bits in size though, that's not really a useful operation to do.

Comment: It tried that too... but result is same

Comment: You'll probably find that shifting by a smaller amount will work. Shifting beyond the range of the data type can result in undefined behaviour. On some builds/compilers it may zero the variable, on others it may fill it with garbage data, or simply do nothing at all. Basically, don't do it. :)

Comment: i don't understand why down votes, it's basically an important issue that why isn't it showing zero because i'm implementing universal hashing and i need it to return 0 (which is quite logical) for my hash function to index hash table

Comment: It might seem logical to you, but it's not how the language is designed. If you want a 0 then just assign 0 manually.

Answer (score 1):

you foget to assign the value to rnd

```
rnd = rnd>>32
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to assign the result:

```
rnd = rnd >> 32;
```