# Bit masks and long-long

Tags: c++

I have a masking procedure (which creates an all-ones bit mask for the bottom half for a given size):

```
template<class T>
T bottom_half() {
    T halfway = ((sizeof(T) * 8) / 2);
    T mask = (1 << halfway) - 1;

    return mask;
}
```

which works fine if I call `bottom_half<int>()` or `long` or `char`. But for some reason when I run it with `long long`, `halfway` is correctly set to `32`, but `mask` is `0`. Why would that be?

Comment: The correct spelling of half the bits of an integer is `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits / 2`. The expression used above assumes a `char` has 8 bit which is required (although I'm not aware of any platform where it is not 8 bits).

Comment: Ah, that's interesting to know, thanks.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I heard Windows CE has byte with 16 bits in it.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: I think what you meant to say is that a `char` is *not* required to be 8 bits. (In fact, it's required to be *at least* 8 bits, and it's exactly bits in most implementations.)

Comment: @Nawaz: I'd be very surprised if Windows CE had `CHAR_BIT==16`. It probably uses 16-bit characters (for UCS-2 and/or UTF-16), but represents them using `wchar_t` or some equivalent. I expect that the predefined type `char` is 8 bits.

Comment: @Nawaz: yes, `char` is _not_ required to have exactly 8 bits. It has at least 8 bits. The only platform I heart rumored to have more than 8 bit `char`s are some Crays which supposedly had 64 bit `char`s.

Comment: @Nawaz - Windows CE still has 8 bit bytes/`char`s, but the string libraries do not support char by choice, to force the programmer to use `wchar_t`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/2098298/364818

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The Crays I worked on had 8-bit `char` (implemented entirely in software) because they ran Unicos, a version of Unix, which requires 8-bit bytes. I don't know about Cray's earlier non-Unix OS.

Comment: @MarkLakata: No, not really: according to 18.3.2.4 [numeric.limits.members] paragraph 8: "`static constexpr int digits`; Number of `radix` digits that can be represented without change." 3.9.1 [basic.fundamental] paragraph 7 states "... The representations of integral types shall define values by use of a pure binary numeration system ..." I'd think this amounts to the radix of the built-in integral types being 2. The number of decimal digits is given by `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10`.

Comment: @DietmarKühl - sorry, you are correct

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The left shift is shifting 1, which is `int` by default and probably 32 bits on your machine. When you shift `1<<32`, the result is undefined, which means it is not predictable anymore, as it could be anything.

On some processors, `1<<32` might result in shifting the bit off the high end of the integer and resulting in 0. On other processors, the 32 shift is modulo the register size, so effective it is a zero shift, and the result is 1. In any case, it is undefined.

(See [What's bad about shifting a 32-bit variable 32 bits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2648764/whats-bad-about-shifting-a-32-bit-variable-32-bits) for a discussion on this).

Note also that `sizeof` returns units `char` or "bytes" (these are defined to be the same in C, `sizeof(char) == 1` always), but C does not guarantee that a byte is 8 bits.  There is standard macro `CHAR_BIT` to get the bit size of a `char`.

Try this

```
#include <limits.h>

template<class T>
T bottom_half() {
    T halfway = ((sizeof(T) * CHAR_BIT) / 2);
    T mask = ((T)1 << halfway) - 1;

    return mask;
}
```

Comment: So you mean `(1 << 32) - 1` is `0`?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: How exactly?

Comment: @Nawaz: if `int` has 32 bit or less, the expression `1 << 32` has undefined behavior.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: yes. that is correct, but this answer doesn't talk about UB, which is why I asked this question.

Comment: @MarkLakata: Yes, your answer is misleading if not wrong. Please correct it if you understand what is wrong with it.

Answer (score 3):

The expression `1 << x` has type `int`. Left-shifting a signed type such that the value exceeds the maximum representable value has undefined behavior. Use `T(1) << x` instead.

Comment: +1. This is the correct answer so far, as it also talks about *"undefined behavior"* in the original code.

Answer (score 0):

Cast the `1` in your shift operation to the correct type. As it is, it's a simple integer and so the shift achieves nothing -- you shift the bit out of existence.